# XPDL to image converter

Tags: image, converters, business-process-management, viewer

Is there some tool to convert xpdl (bpm descriptor) to image files?

I need to convert a bunch of this bpm descriptor to images and doing that manually with some editor is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

ELMA BPM designer in addition to many other things allows to import XPDL files and export them to image file or print.